# How Many Mondays, Tuesdays etc

Tags: sql

I am trying to work out how many items in average I am selling per day, at the moment I have the total QTY per done done when i bring the data into a pivot table in excel but when i try and use the Average it seems to be taking the average per "sale" which is usually one.

ideally if i have sold 50 of x items and there are 4 Mondays I want this to be 50 / 4 so i "sell 12.5 on average per Monday)

I thought the best way to do this is get another column that has x amount of Monday etc and then just do a calculated field to do this.

the code I have is

```
SELECT TransactionsLine.TransactionID
      ,StockItems.Description as 'Item'
      ,[ItemQuantity]
      ,[Amount]
      ,[DiscountedAmount]
      ,[Cost]
      ,Departments.Description as 'Product Type'
      ,Name
      ,Locations.Description as 'Location'
      ,YEAR(Date) AS Year,
      datename(m,Date) AS Month,
      datename(dw,Date) AS Day,
      Date
  FROM [IPSTransaction].[dbo].[TransactionsLine]
  left join StockItems  on TransactionsLine.StockItemID = StockItems.ID
  left join Departments on TransactionsLine.Department = Departments.Code
  left join Clerk       on TransactionsLine.ClerkID = Clerk.ID
 left join Transactions on TransactionsLine.TransactionID = Transactions.id
 left join Locations on  Transactions.Location = Locations.Code
 WHERE
YEAR(Date) = YEAR(GETDATE())
    and 
    TransactionTypeID = '5'
    order by Date
```

if i am thinking about this all wrong please let me know

Answer (score 0):

If I'm interpreting you question correctly you would like to add one average for every day of the week? If that is the case, I think something like this could be useful:

```
,Sum([ItemQuantity]/Count(datename(dw,Date)) As Average_Per_Day
```

Then you would need to add a Group By, and just add every line above the SUM line, so ideally if that is on the bottom everything would be added again in Group By.
If there are individual rows for each item, like in the case of your query, the line Average_Per_Day would appear as a duplicate each day that it appear, so for every monday you would have x and for every tuesday you would have y, even though the sales for each monday can be 3x or 2x etc.

I hope it helps :)

Comment: Hey Wilhelm, thanks for your reply i will give this a go when i have some more coffee :)

If we take Feb for example i would like the Average to be :

Mon - 4
Tue - 4
Wed - 4
Thur - 4 
Fri - 4
Sat - 4
Sun - 4

so then i can do 50 x / how many Mondays 

i was going to just do a divide by 4 but then it wouldn't be accurate at a MTD function / if the month has 5 Mondays etc

Was hoping to just make my pivot table do it but it averages the QTY on the individual order not the overall QTY